# Cyrillic characters are stored as "?" in exif

Tags: android, character-encoding, exif, charsequence

I create photo. I need to add a user comment in exif.
I try next code

```
 @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if (exifInterface != null){
        try {
            exifInterface.setAttribute("UserComment", charSequence.toString());
            exifInterface.saveAttributes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to convert a string to UTF-8

```
exifInterface.setAttribute("UserComment", new String(charSequence.toString().getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
```

Cyrillic characters are stored as "?"

Help!

Comment: You need to elaborate more on this

Comment: I need to add a UserComment tag in exif to the saved photo file. I do this with the help of the water mentioned above, but he inserts the symbol "?" Instead of Cyrillic.

Comment: How correct save cyrillic characters in file to exif?